# Metapost (Graph) LuaLaTeX: intersectionpoint - graph with line not what intended - why?

Tags: luatex, metapost

Good morning!
Trying around as MP-Newbie since days to get a correct intersection between my graph p and a horizontal line in red.

The point in my example is at the red trianlge in the left bottom.

The data from my graph p are in an external file called `data.txt` an called via graph-package routines.

My actual code is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{gobble}

\begin{mplibcode}
prologues := 3;

defaultfont := "phvr8r";
defaultfontscale := 0.92*8pt/fontsize defaultfont;

input graph;

Gtemplate.itick:=origin--(4bp,0);
Gtemplate.otick:=(-4bp,0)--origin;

beginfig(1)
draw begingraph(100bp*u,100bp*u);
path p, q; % p ... curve, q ... red line
pair n;       % n ... should be the intersection point ->    gives error during compilation
u = 3;

% Data from data.txt - the six pts are as black points on the curve p.
p:=(1,1){right}
   gdata("data.txt",$, ..(scantokens $1, scantokens $2));
gdraw p 
   plot btex \raisebox{-0.5\height}{\makebox[0pt]   {$\bullet$}} etex 
     withpen pencircle scaled 1bp;   


 % Grid vertikal
 autogrid(,);  
 for x=0 step 10 until 100:
 grid.bot (format("%0f", x),x) withpen pencircle scaled 0.22bp withcolor 0.6 white;
  endfor
% Grid horizontal
autogrid(,); 
for y=0 step 10 until 100:
grid.lft (format("%0f ", y),y) withpen pencircle scaled 0.22bp withcolor 0.6 white;
  endfor
setrange(-3,-3,103,103);

% upper red line
z1 = (0,87.5*u); z2= (100*u,87.5*u);
q = z1 -- z2; 
draw q withcolor red;

%n = p intersectionpoint q; % gives the error when uncommented

% define the intersection point of the curve with the red line - it actually gives the red triangle at origin in my graph.
label.bot(btex $\color{red}\triangle$ etex, 
  (z1 -- z2) intersectiontimes p);

endgraph;

endfig;
end


\end{mplibcode}

\end{document}
```

[image: my result with red triangle at origin instead of intersectionpoint]

My file `data.txt` contains the following points (they are written two numbers in a line only with spaces and CR, the double slash is for better readability):

> 1 1 //
>   5 2 //
>   22 30 //
>   26.5 50 //
>   45 80 //
>   62  90 //
>   98  99

Any help or hints would be warmly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I'd keep it a bit simpler than that -- the graph library has some useful facilities, but it adds a more complex interface.  You can do everything you want for that particular chart more simply with plain MP.  And you get more control...

Here is a version drawn with plain MP (and with the red line shifted to 87 instead of 90 just to show that it works anywhere).

[image: curve and line on a grid]

I've added comments explaining each section.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luatex85}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(1);
    % define the unit size
    numeric u;
    u = 1mm;

    % define the axes first 
    path xx, yy;
    xx = (3 left -- 103 right) scaled u;
    yy = xx rotated 90;

    % now the two lines to mark
    path p, q;
    p = ((1, 1) .. (5,2) .. (22,30) .. (26.5,50) .. (45,80) .. (62,90) .. (98,99)) scaled u;
    q = xx shifted (0, 87u);

    % and a triangular marker
    path t;
    t = (for i=0 upto 2: up rotated 120i -- endfor cycle) scaled u;

    % draw and label the grid
    for i=0 step 10 until 100:
        draw xx shifted(0, i*u) withcolor 3/4 white;
        draw yy shifted(i*u, 0) withcolor 3/4 white;

        label.lft("$" & decimal i & "$", point 0 of xx shifted (0, i*u));
        label.bot("$" & decimal i & "$", point 0 of yy shifted (i*u, 0));
    endfor
    % and a box round it
    draw unitsquare scaled arclength(xx) 
                    shifted (xpart point 0 of xx, ypart point 0 of yy);

    % now draw the two lines
    draw q withcolor 2/3 red;
    draw p;

    % mark all the points along p
    for i=0 upto length p: 
        drawdot point i of p withpen pencircle scaled dotlabeldiam; 
    endfor

    % add the marker in red
    draw t shifted (p intersectionpoint q) 
           shifted 8 down 
           withcolor 2/3 red;

endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 10):

You need to use `intersectionpoint` to get an intersection point, `intersectiontimes` only returns the "time" at which both paths reach the point. For example if both paths would start at the same point, `intersectiontimes` would return `(0,0)` because the intersection is at the beginning, time `0`. If it is at the beginning of `p` and the second control point of `q`, then `p intersectiontimes q` would return `(0,1)`.

You course these pairs do not represent coordinates and drawing them would result in sime points near the origin.

The code already mentions `intersectionpoint` but says it "gives the error". The error in question is

```
! The paths don't intersect.
```

If MetaPost thinks the paths do not intersect, how can it compute the `intersectiontimes`? The `intersectiontimes` of two non intersecting paths is by definition `(-1, -1)` (using the fact that `-1` is not a valid time), so `intersectiontimes` does not throw an error but returns a marker instead.

But why do the paths not intersect? According to MetaPost the paths are

```
>> Path at line 43:
(1,1)..controls (1,1) and (1,1)
 ..(1,1)..controls (2.36905,1.16934) and (3.71233,1.50516)
 ..(5,2)..controls (15.8229,6.15913) and (19.67946,18.41534)
 ..(22,30)..controls (23.3429,36.70403) and (24.53044,43.45076)
 ..(26.5,50)..controls (29.95534,61.48978) and (35.82167,72.26625)
 ..(45,80)..controls (50.05702,84.2611) and (55.92546,87.39604)
 ..(62,90)..controls (73.44186,94.90475) and (85.59612,97.94331)
 ..(98,99)


>> Path at line 44:
(0,262.5)..controls (100,262.5) and (200,262.5)
 ..(300,262.5)
```

You can see that the `y` values of the first graph never exceed `100`, but the `y` values of the second graph  are `262.5`.
They still intersect in the drawing because they are given in different coordinate systems:

The first graph with the values from `data.txt` contains exactly the coordinates from the file and is then drawn by `gdraw` which transforms these into the actual dimensions in the output.
The second path is directly given in the output coordinates (the (implicit) unit is `bp`) and drawn by `draw` which does not apply further transformations by default.

So the paths do not intersect, but the transformed paths in the output do.

How do we fix this? The easiest way is to change `q` (the red line) to use the graph coordinates and then use `gdraw/glabel` instead of `draw/label`: Replace

```
z1 = (0,87.5*u); z2= (100*u,87.5*u);
q = z1 -- z2; 
draw q withcolor red;

%n = p intersectionpoint q; % gives the error when uncommented

% define the intersection point of the curve with the red line - it actually gives the red triangle at origin in my graph.
label.bot(btex $\color{red}\triangle$ etex, 
  (z1 -- z2) intersectiontimes p);
```

with

```
z1 = (-3,90); z2= (103,90);
q = z1 -- z2; 
gdraw q withcolor red;

n = p intersectionpoint q;

% define the intersection point of the curve with the red line
glabel.bot(btex $\color{red}\triangle$ etex, n);
```

[image]